# How to define the constraint by using cplex library?

Tags: cplex

When I created a constraint in pycharm with cplex library, there is an error as follows.
Could anyone tell me what should I do, please? Thank you in advance.

```
import cplex
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='Marking Optimization')
inf = cplex.infinity
bigM= 1000000

n = 2 

p = [40,100] 
c = [20,100]
v = 3 
w = 5 

m = [1,3]


y = mdl.integer_var(lb = 0, ub=inf, name='y')

#constraint 15
mdl.add_constraint(1 >= y*(n+1)*(2*v + 2*w)

#constraint 16
mdl.add_constraint(1 >= (y*1/m[i])*(p[i] + c[i] + 2*w) for i in range(n))
```

In addition, there is also error when I used following code.

```
#constraint 16
for i in range(n):
mdl.add_constraint(1 >= (y*1/m[i])*(p[i] + c[i] + 2*w))
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraint #15 has no closing parenthesis.
Constraint #16 should use add_constraint**s** abd use a list.

```
#constraint 15
mdl.add_constraint(1 >= y*(n+1)*(2*v + 2*w))

#constraint 16
mdl.add_constraints([1 >= (y*1/m[i])*(p[i] + c[i] + 2*w) for i in range(n)])
```